# Xamarin forms tree view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, treeview

I'm trying to implement a treeview with nested data in Xamarin forms. Something that looks like this
[image]

Tapping on each item opens a list of possible sub items. The examples I've seen online only deal with one layer of data using a ListView. Is it possible to implement such  hierarchical view of data in xamarin forms.

Comment: Something like this [HighEnergy.TreeView](https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView) ?

Comment: Yes that would work. Ended up using the idea from the link to build my own tree using stacklayouts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListView x:Name="GroupedView" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Header}" RowHeight="75" IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout HeightRequest="{Binding height}">
          <Label Text="{Binding MenuText}"  TextColor="Green" >
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
          </Label>
          <ScrollView>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding submenuitems}"  HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="{Binding expand}">
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Margin="25,5,5,5" HeightRequest="{Binding height}">
                      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"/>
                      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>                      
                      <Label Text="{Binding MenuText}"  TextColor="DarkBlue"/>
                      <ScrollView>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding submenuitems_2}" HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="{Binding expand}">
                          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                              <ViewCell >
                                <StackLayout Margin="35,10,5,5" HeightRequest="45">
                                  <Label Text="{Binding MenuText}"  TextColor="Red"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                              </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                      </ScrollView>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
          </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5" BackgroundColor="#E2F5F9">
          <Button Image="{Binding StateIcon}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" Clicked="HeaderTapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Header}" TextColor="#005569" FontSize="15" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea nesting `ScrollView` in `ScrollView` or `ListView`. There are some negative side effects, when using this in production ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. I implemented a TreeView by nesting StackPanels inside StackPanels.

You can download the code here:
https://github.com/AdaptSolutions/Xamarin.Forms-TreeView

Here is some example code:

```
     private void Render()
        {
            _SpacerBoxView.WidthRequest = IndentWidth;

            if (Children == null || Children.Count == 0)
            {
                SetExpandButtonContent(BlankImagePath);
                return;
            }

            SetExpandButtonContent(IsExpanded ? OpenImagePath : CollapseImagePath);

            foreach (var item in Children)
            {
                item.Render();
            }
        }
```