# Multilevel Listview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, expandablelistview

I need to make a Multilevel Listview in Xamarin forms.

Currently, I am using this for my Single level Grouping in my Menu Page

http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview

I need to update something like the attached image.  I have tried some of the Solution but all in vain.

Anyone has any idea about this.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: there are third party treeview controls you could try, but in general trying to do this with a ListView is a bad idea.  Personally if I had to do something like this I would navigate to a new listview as I drilled down into each subsection

Comment: Can you throw some light that'll be great.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/treeview/treeview-getting-started
and
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/treeview/getting-started

Comment: Problem is we are using Devexpress xamarin forms control and they don't have any such controls. We can't go for any other third party control for now.

Comment: Don't try to nest ListView inside ListView. Instead, you need to implement a tree view (unfortunately there isn't one built into Xamarin). Surprisingly I don't see any open source ones. For a menu, where the tree is static, all you need is a way to "expand" and "collapse" nodes. [This answer using StackLayouts might get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53316058/199364).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `Expander` of `Xamarin Community Toolkit`.

Install `Xamarin Community Toolkit` from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/

Usage:  `xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"`

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:RootViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView Margin="20">
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding roots}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xct:Expander>
                        <xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Root}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large" />
                        </xct:Expander.Header>

                        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Node}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>                                        
                                    <xct:Expander Padding="10">
                                        <xct:Expander.Header>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Key.Node}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                        </xct:Expander.Header>
                                        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding SubRoot}"  FontSize="Small" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </xct:Expander>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </xct:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Model:

```
 public class Roots
{
    public string Root { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Nodes, List<SubRoots>> Node { get; set; }        

}
public class Nodes
{
    public string Node { get; set; }
}
public class SubRoots
{
    public string SubRoot { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class RootViewModel
{
    public List<Roots> roots { get; private set; }
    public RootViewModel()
    {
        CreateMonkeyCollection();
    }
    public void CreateMonkeyCollection()
    {
      
        List<SubRoots> subRoot = new List<SubRoots>() { new SubRoots() { SubRoot = "SubNode" } };
        Dictionary<Nodes, List<SubRoots>> node = new Dictionary<Nodes, List<SubRoots>>();
        node.Add(new Nodes() {  Node="Nodo1"}, null);
        node.Add(new Nodes() {  Node="Nodo2"}, null);
        node.Add(new Nodes() {  Node="Nodo3"}, null);
        node.Add(new Nodes() {  Node="Nodo4"}, subRoot);

        roots = new List<Roots>()
        {
            new Roots(){ Root="Root1", Node=node},
            new Roots(){ Root="Root2", Node= null}

        };

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Wendy. I am able to create what I want. That's a pretty nice solution. However, one thing that I tried to do is open one expander at a time. I tried some things but again couldn't achieve what I want. Also, look for some in sites but mostly for WPF. Any idea how we can do in your solution.

Comment: Bing the IsExpanded property to control. Check the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630688/at-a-time-only-one-expander-expand-on-xamarin-form/67669191#67669191

Comment: Thanks, wendy, I forgot to post I am able to achieve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wendy sorry to trouble you again. Any help where I can set the background colour for my selected Item in this List just like ListViewItem. I have done but I am not very happy with the code as I have traverse with Many parents and children then I set tapped expander and Stacklayout background and reset the previously selected expander which I find not a good idea to do. Please let me know if there is any simple approach to do this.