# At a time only one expander expand on xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, expandablelistview

On my page there is a 4 expander ,I want to write a code for at a time one expander is expand ,What can I do for this scenario please help me ,For more clarifications I have a add image of expanders ,In this given code there is a one expander show ,but this type of a 4 expander available on my page and i want to expand one at a time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QNbG.png)

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Synonyms,Converter={x:StaticResource CorrectionTypeVisiableConverter}}" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <xct:Expander ExpandAnimationEasing="CubicIn"
                                                         ExpandAnimationLength="500"
                                                          CollapseAnimationEasing="CubicOut"
                                                          CollapseAnimationLength="500">
                                                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                                                        <Frame  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" HasShadow="False" >
                                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                                <xct:BadgeView Text="{Binding Synonyms,Converter={StaticResource CorrectionCountBadgeConverter}}"  BackgroundColor="#FADBD8" BadgePosition="TopLeft"   TextColor="#E74C3C" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="16"  AutoHide="True"                                                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                                    <Label Text=""></Label>
                                                                </xct:BadgeView>
                                                                <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Synonyms}"
                                                                        FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                                        FontSize="Medium" Style="{StaticResource MenueLableStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                                                <Image Source="Expand.png"
                                                                         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                                                Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}},                                                                              Path=IsExpanded,Mode=OneTime}"
                                                                                Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Source"
                                                                                Value="collapse.png" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                                                </Image>
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </Frame>
                                                    </xct:Expander.Header>
                                                    <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" HasShadow="False" >
                                                                            <Grid >
                                                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                                    <Label  Text="{Binding s}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                                                    </Label>
                                                                                    <Label  Text="--->" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                        <xct:BadgeView Grid.Column="0" Text=""  BackgroundColor="#FADBD8" BadgePosition="TopRight" TextColor="#E74C3C" FontSize="14"                                                                                                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AutoHide="True"                                                                                                VerticalOptions="Center" Background="#FADBD8" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="25">
                                                                                            <Label Text="{Binding c}"></Label>
                                                                                        </xct:BadgeView>
                                                                                        <ImageButton Grid.Column="0" Source="Storyedit.png" 
                                                                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"   WidthRequest="12" HeightRequest="12"/>
                                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                                    <ImageButton Source="Info.png" Command="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CorrectionInfoCommand,Source={x:Reference Name=storyView}}" 
                                                                                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                                                </StackLayout>
                                                                                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.IgnoreButton}"                                                                                    Style="{StaticResource CancelButton}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"                                                                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ></Button>
                                                                                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AcceptButton}"                                                                                 Style="{StaticResource AcceptButton}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"                                                                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" ></Button>

                                                                                <FlexLayout  IsVisible="False" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                                                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AlignItems="Start" AlignContent="Center"                                                                                Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="Center">
                                                                                    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.IgnoreButton}" Padding="5"                                                                                    Style="{StaticResource CancelButton}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Button>
                                                                                    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.IgnoreAllButton}" Style="{StaticResource                                                                        CancelButton}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="5"></Button>
                                                                                    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AcceptButton}" Style="{StaticResource                                                                        AcceptButton}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="5"></Button>
                                                                                    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AcceptAllButton}" Style="{StaticResource                                                                      AcceptButton}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="5"></Button>
                                                                                </FlexLayout>
                                                                            </Grid>
                                                                        </Frame>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                                                </xct:Expander>
                                            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What is the 4 expanders mean? Do you want to do something like multiple levels? Please check the link i done before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559174/multilevel-listview-in-xamarin-forms/67581230#67581230

Comment: 4 different different expanders available on my page and I want to expand one at a time

Comment: Could you provide your model and viewmodel with error messages?

Comment: I don't have any error message ,I have a add one image link in question in this image I have shown my output ,In this output there is a 3 expander view .The problem is this expander are expand when we click ,but I want to show only one expander open at a time other should be collaps

Comment: you will need an event handler that closes all the other expanders when one is opened.  There is no automated way to do this, you will need to write the code yourself.

Comment: @jason pleses give me a event code for that expander .

Answer (score 0):

You could binding true or false for the IsExpanded property to indicate that the Expander is expanded or collapsed.

I make a simple example for your reference.

Model:

```
  public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region fields
    public string _synonyms;
    public string _s;
    public bool _isexpand;
    #endregion
    public string Synonyms
    {
        get { return _synonyms; }
        set { _synonyms = value; OnPropertyChanged("Synonyms"); }
    }
    public string s
    {
        get { return _s; }
        set { _s = value; OnPropertyChanged("s"); }
    }
    public bool ISexpand
    {
        get { return _isexpand; }
        set { _isexpand = value; OnPropertyChanged("ISexpand"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel1
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> models { get; set; }
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        CreateCollection();
    }
    public void CreateCollection()
    {
        models = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
        {
            new Model(){ Synonyms="Synonym1", s="A", ISexpand=false},
            new Model(){ Synonyms="Synonym2", s="B",ISexpand=false},
            new Model(){ Synonyms="Synonym3", s="C",ISexpand=false},
            new Model(){ Synonyms="Synonym4", s="D",ISexpand=false},
            new Model(){ Synonyms="Synonym5", s="E",ISexpand=false},
        };
    }

}
```

Xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel1></local:ViewModel1>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout"  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding models}" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xct:Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ISexpand}"  Tapped="Expander_Tapped" >
                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Synonyms}"></Label>
                    </xct:Expander.Header>
                    <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                               
                                <Label Text="{Binding s}"></Label>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </xct:Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{
    ViewModel1 viewModel1=new ViewModel1();
    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    int i = 0;
    private void Expander_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = sender as Expander;
        var label = expander.Header as Label;
        var list = viewModel1.models;
        foreach (var item in viewModel1.models)
        {
            if (item.Synonyms == label.Text)
            {
                item.ISexpand = true;
           
           
                if (i >= 1)
                {
                    foreach (var item1 in viewModel1.models.ToList())
                    {
                        if (item1.Synonyms!= label.Text)
                        {
                            item1.ISexpand = false;
                          
                        }
                    }
                    BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stacklayout, viewModel1.models);
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

OutPut:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz17x.jpg