# xamarin.forms bind to deeper elements of object

Tags: xamarin.forms

From our API I am getting objects inside objects:

[image]

And I am trying to display it in a list very similar to the one in the screenshot.

```
<CollectionView
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    x:Name="listview_list">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding layer1Visible}">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding type}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

But here you already see the problem,
when i click on one element and "open" it up, I am binding to `type` but this is always shown as an empty label. But there is data on my list, it just wont display, as the property is on step further "in" into the model AND it exists multiple times (4 times in this example)

How can I access this data and also show a list of multiple sublayouts that dont themselves scoll but scroll with the parent (exactly how the one from visual studio in the screenshot)

thank you

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to display a tree like structure - CollectionView is not really suited for this.  There are free and commercial TreeView controls you can try instead

Comment: I tried a few, but didnt find any suiteable free for xamarin.forms. I was able to bend collectioniew to display the tree as intended, but its a bit laggy...

Comment: You can't get there from here. You won't be able to bind that xaml to deeper items that there are multiple of. Making a working tree viewer is an **advanced** topic. If you want to pursue it, and you can't find a free one that does what you need, google `github xamarin forms tree list`. If you find any xamarin forms tree project in github, even if it doesn't do everything you need, download it, and start with that. Try to make changes; when you get stuck, post a question based on that source.

Comment: Similar with [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559174/multilevel-listview-in-xamarin-forms)?