# How to create Expander in codebehind inside For Loop in xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Here `contentItems[0]` have Headers of content and `contentItems[1]` have Paragraph of Header. I would like to display Paragraph inside header in Xamarin Expander.

After run this code getting **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

```
 public partial class TermsAndConditionsPage : ContentPage
{
    private TermsAndConditionsViewModel _Model;     
    public TermsAndConditionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
        _Model = new TermsAndConditionsViewModel(Navigation);
        BindingContext = _Model;

        for (int i = 1; i < _Model.contentList.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] contentItems = _Model.contentList[i].Split("\n", 2);

            Console.WriteLine("Printing Header of Content... \n");
            Console.WriteLine(contentItems[0]);

            Console.WriteLine("Printing Paragraph of Header... \n");
            Console.WriteLine(contentItems[1]);

            Expander expander = new Expander
            {
                Header = new Label
                {
                    Text = contentItems[0],
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))
                }
            };

            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
                }
            };

            grid.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = contentItems[1],
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic
            }, 1, 0);

            expander.Content = grid;

        }
    }     
}
```

Output like this image but i need multiple expanders depends on array.
[Output like this image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5jX.png)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to determine which line throws the error, then determine what on that line is null. Also take a look at using a BindableLayout or CollectionView do this. It will be much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the layout in code behind, add the code below in the end of your page constructure.

```
 Content = expander;
```

If you want to display the expander for one level, you could check the sample in the below. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/ExpanderDemos

If you want to show multilevels like below, you could use multiple explanders inside stacklayout.

[image]

```
 <ScrollView Margin="20">
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding roots}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xct:Expander>
                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Root}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Large" />
                    </xct:Expander.Header>

                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Node}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                                        
                                <xct:Expander Padding="10">
                                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Key.Node}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </xct:Expander.Header>
                                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding SubRoot}"  FontSize="Small" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </xct:Expander>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </xct:Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For more details with view model, you could refer to the thread i done before.
[Multilevel Listview in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559174/multilevel-listview-in-xamarin-forms/67581230#67581230)

Comment: I'm working on it, Thank you so much. @Wendy